# Referential constraint based on substring of value in EF4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

In EF4 is it possible to have a referential contstraint which is based upon just a substring of a value?

e.g.

Ref table:
Code: varchar(5)
Desc: varchar(50)

Main Table:
Code: varchar(6)
Data1:
Data2: etc...

I would like to have a constraint where `MainTable.Code.Substring(0,5) > RefTable.Code`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible and I doubt that you can create such relation in database - EF follows same rules as relational database.

Edit: Actually there can be a way to achieve that if you try to represent it as a query inside [QueryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716798.aspx).